# Docker container as network gateway [Not responding]

Tags: iptables, docker, routing, wireguard

I wanted to set up a Wireguard Docker container acting as a network gateway.

My setup looks like this:

```
Client (user-Virtual-Machine) | IP: 172.22.100.157  
Host (user-Virtual-Machine) | IP: 172.22.105.35  
Docker container (from linuxserver/wireguard) | IP: 172.16.238.10
```

---

What I've done so far:

Client:

```
# Replace the default route with the hosts's IP
$ ip route replace default via 172.22.105.35
```

Host:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding true

# Define default route in a new routing table
$ ip route add default via 172.16.238.10 table 200
# Requests for the docker network via the docker interface IP
$ ip route add 172.16.238.0/24 via 172.16.238.1 table 200
# Lookup new routing table for all request coming into the interface eth0 (from Client Network)
$ ip rule add iif eth0 lookup 200

$ iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br-06b8cf6f4319 -j MASQUERADE
$ iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o br-06b8cf6f4319 -j ACCEPT
```

Container:

- IP forwarding is enabled by default in this docker image

[In the wireguard config file]

```
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o  %i -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o  %i -j MASQUERADE
```

---

This is what happens when I try pinging a web server from the client:

Client:

```
root@user-Virtual-Machine:~# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Host:

```
root@user-Virtual-Machine:/home/user/docker# tcpdump -i br-b1b1ac41a7f9 -n -v
tcpdump: listening on br-b1b1ac41a7f9, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:48:06.413006 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 35526, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.22.100.157 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 35, seq 1, length 64
15:48:06.413170 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52489, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 156)
    172.16.238.10.46677 > 195.181.170.67.443: UDP, length 128
15:48:06.435470 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 20187, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    195.181.170.67.443 > 172.16.238.10.46677: UDP, length 116
15:48:06.435656 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52492, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 156)
    172.16.238.10.46677 > 195.181.170.67.443: UDP, length 128
^C
4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

[image: In Whireshark]

Container:

```
root@5f21c444a297:/# tcpdump -n -v
tcpdump: listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
13:06:38.860868 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 35630, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    100.64.67.64 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 19, seq 1, length 64
13:06:38.885219 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 10501, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    1.1.1.1 > 100.64.67.64: ICMP echo reply, id 19, seq 1, length 64
13:06:38.885256 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 58, id 10501, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    1.1.1.1 > 172.22.100.157: ICMP echo reply, id 19, seq 1, length 64
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Do you need IP forwarding on in the gateway?

Comment: IP forwarding is enabled on the gateway and on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks @user1794469 your comment brought me on the right track.

The problem was that the interface eth0 inside of the docker container is not on the same subnet as the client and the default **rule** is to look up the routing table "51820" which is created by `wg-quick` when starting the Wireguard interface.
Thus the request was successfully forwarded to - and send over the Wireguard interface, but the response, as the IP of the client wasn't in a subnet known to the container, was treated like any other packet belonging to the WAN (internet) and was also sent over the Wireguard interface.

Request: Client *[eth0]* -> *[eth0]* Host *[br-b1b1ac41a7f9]* -> Container *[eth0]* [NAT] *[wg0]*  -> ... -> WAN
Response: WAN -> ... -> *[wg0]* Container *[wg0]* -> ... -> WAN

You just have to add a route to the subnet the clients are in via the gateway of the docker container (the IP of the bridge interface on the host):

```
$ ip route
default via <gateway> dev eth0

$ ip route add <client_subnet> via <gateway>
```

However, it is more convenient to add this to the `PostUp` section of the Wireguard config file. Which could look like this:

```
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o  %i -j MASQUERADE && ip route add 172.22.100.0/24 via 172.16.238.1
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o  %i -j MASQUERADE && ip route delete 172.22.100.0/24 via 172.16.238.1
```

Another way is to setup NAT masquerading on the host:

`$ iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o <container_bridge_interface> -j MASQUERADE`

In this example:

`$ iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br-b1b1ac41a7f9 -j MASQUERADE`